# Best way to insert hundreds of DOM elements into the page dynamically while keeping performance high

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a web app where we would be inserting hundreds of elements into the DOM

Essentially, I'm doing

```
 $('#some_element').html('<lots of html here>');
```

repeatedly. In some cases I might need to do `$('#some_element').appendTo('more html');`

From previous experience inserting html text using the append or setting the `innerHTML` of an element is slow.

I've heard that you can increase performance by first putting the elements in a DOM fragment and then moving its location to inside the element you want.

The performance of this is key. Do you guys have any tips or suggestions on maximizing the performance? Any hacks I can do to make this fast?

Edit: as mentioned in a comment: The app involves a real-time stream of various data, so it needs to be able to constantly add new DOM elements to represent the new data. (This might also lead to another problem of having too many DOM elements, so would need to elements that are too old).

Comment: Given the requirements, your current approach seems reasonable. Does it feel slow currently?

Comment: Yea, there's a tiny lag as the browser renders the new html. So the browser feels frozen for 300ms to 600ms. But as there's more data I don't want that increase, which is what I'm worried about.

Comment: Can you provide a sample web-page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just don't do `html()` (or use its native cousin `innerHTML = …`) *repeatedly*. Pack your HTML in one variable and do `html()` only once (or as few times as possible). E.g.:

```
var buf = [], i = 0;

buf[i++] = "<p>";               /* or use buf.push(string) */
buf[i++] = "some text";
buf[i++] = "some other text";
buf[i++] = "</p>";

element.innerHTML = buf.join("");
```

Also see the [Quirksmode entry on innerHTML](http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t03) and the [W3C DOM vs. innerHTML](http://quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html) page.

**Update:** Yesterday I found the amazing article [When innerHTML isn't Fast Enough](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-than-innerhtml) by Steven Levithan about his function `replaceHtml`, which is even faster than using just `innerHTML`, because it removes the DOM nodes that are to be replaced using standard DOM manipulation *before* `innerHTML` is used:

```
function replaceHtml(el, html) {
    var oldEl = typeof el === "string" ? document.getElementById(el) : el;
    /*@cc_on // Pure innerHTML is slightly faster in IE
        oldEl.innerHTML = html;
        return oldEl;
    @*/
    var newEl = oldEl.cloneNode(false);
    newEl.innerHTML = html;
    oldEl.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, oldEl);
    /* Since we just removed the old element from the DOM, return a reference
    to the new element, which can be used to restore variable references. */
    return newEl;
};
```

Comment: The app involves a real-time stream of various data, so it needs to be able to constantly add new DOM elements.

Comment: @rksprst: but if you do this in one run, you won't notice, as script execution blocks rerendering. “[F]irst putting the elements in a DOM fragment and then moving its location to inside the element” is actually what I'm showing. There's no faster way, at least as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the help, fairly late down the track, just a tip for others - I found I had to add var buf = [], i = 0; to get my code working.

Comment: @dpmguise – Whoops, good catch. Corrected and updated with new material.

Comment: For those of you finding `replaceHtml` a interesting idea, please run this benchmark on your browser http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/replaceHtml.html. I've found that in the latest Chromium, there's no difference at all between the two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify what Marcel said in his answer:

DOM manipulation (using appendTo, creating Element's, TextNode's, etc) is orders of magnitudes slower than just read/writing innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Real time streaming should **update** not append. As mentioned, use a buffer. Another thing you could do is.

```
var buffer = [];
setInterval(function(){ $("#div").html(buffer.join(""); buffer = []; }, 1000);

buffer.push("html");
buffer.push("html");
```

Set the timeout to whatever you need and it will flush the buffer and append it.

Here is a function and interval you can use.

```
var buffer = [];
var wait = 1000; /* ms to wait, 1000 = 1 second */
var htmlId = "puthere"; /* Change this to the div ID */

setInterval(function(){
    var tmp = buffer; /* Switch the buffer out quickly so we aren't scrambled 
                         if you addToBuffer in the middle of this */
    buffer = [];
    document.getElementById(htmlId).innerHTML = tmp.join("");
}, wait);

addToBuffer = function(html){
    buffer.push(html);
};
```

Comment: JS concurrency doesn't work that way; you can't be descheduled "in the middle of this".

Comment: @raylu Good point, thanks. This answer is pre-dates a lot of my JS experience.